# Update angular View based on http request dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm a beginner with angular and i'm trying to update a view based on a http request.

```
$scope.update = function(id){
      switch (id) {
        case 1:
        $http.get(Backand.getApiUrl() + '/1/objects/details')
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.details = response.data.data[0];
            $rootScope.locName = response.data.data[0].locationName;
            $rootScope.locSubTitle = response.data.data[0].locationSubTitle;
            $rootScope.locParagraph = response.data.data[0].locationParagraph;
            $rootScope.locGluten = response.data.data[0].glutenfrei;
            $rootScope.locRaucher = response.data.data[0].raucher;
            $rootScope.locGarten = response.data.data[0].garten;
            $rootScope.locTakeAway = response.data.data[0].takeaway;
            $rootScope.locRollstuhl = response.data.data[0].rollstuhl;
            console.log($rootScope.locGluten);
        });
        break;
          case 2:
          $http.get(Backand.getApiUrl() + '/1/objects/details')
          .then(function(response) {
            $rootScope.locName = response.data.data[1].locationName;
            $rootScope.locSubTitle = response.data.data[1].locationSubTitle;
            $rootScope.locParagraph = response.data.data[1].locationParagraph;
            $rootScope.locGluten = response.data.data[1].glutenfrei;
            $rootScope.locRaucher = response.data.data[1].raucher;
            $rootScope.locGarten = response.data.data[1].garten;
            $rootScope.locTakeAway = response.data.data[1].takeaway;
            $rootScope.locRollstuhl = response.data.data[1].rollstuhl;

          });
            break;
        default:

      }
    }


    $scope.goToDetail = function(id) {
      $state.go("detail")
      $scope.update(id);

    }
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="cat in content" class="animated lightSpeedIn">
      <a ng-click="goToDetail(cat.id)" nav-transition="none"><div ng-style="{'background': 'url(' + cat.catBgUrl + ')','background-repeat': 'no-repeat','background-size': '100% 100%','display': 'block','width': '100%','height': '25vh' }" class="bgcat center">
        <div class="inner">
          <h1>{{cat.catName}}</h1>
          <h4>{{cat.catSubtitle}}</h4>
          <img src="img/home/open.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div></a>
    </div>
```

I know this is bad code but my thoughts were that go to the state details and run the function update with the id of the entry. Then switch trough the id and update the view based on the clicked element.

The code works fine, but i think there is a much better way to do it and i need it dynamically.

I'm really stuck with this and would like to do it correctly. How should it be made? Can you give me a hint please?

Comment: please provide cat object

Comment: Why are you updating $rootScope and not $scope?

Comment: $scope doesn't work because it's referencing to the function update(). I tried every thing. My goal is that the id automatically increases as long the cat.is has a value in the ng-repeat.

Comment: can't you just make the $http request on another controller after you change routes? You can define parameters on the routes that you would be creating. and another thing, avoid using $rootScope

Comment: How can I create parameters? So that the details view shows the correct data from the huge json object. I can't use ng repeat and would have to show the entry which fits together with the id of the category.

Comment: @olivier are you looking for something like this - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/YWjVZR

Comment: you can pass params when changing state: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for codes relating to data it is better to use services for separation.

**Your service**
```

let **`app`** be your angular module

```
app.service('detailService',function($http){
    var update = function(id,callback){
        switch (id) {
            case 1:
               $http.get(Backand.getApiUrl() + '/1/objects/details')
               .then(function(response) {
                   callback(response,0);
               });
            break;
            case 2:
               $http.get(Backand.getApiUrl() + '/1/objects/details')
               .then(function(response) {
                   callback(response,1);
               });
            break;
    };
});

**Your controller**

app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$state,detailService){
    detailService.update(id,function(response,index){
        $scope.response = response;
        $scope.index = index;
        $state.go("detail"):
    });
});

**You can display the response as**

<p>Details : {{response.data.data[{{index}}]}}</p>
<p>Location Name : {{response.data.data[{{index}}].locationName}}</p>
```

Comment: Thank you very very much that already help alot! Can you give me a hint how i could increase the data array location? For example when the id is 1 then response.data.data[0].locationName when the id is 2 then response.data.data[1].locationName

Comment: I have changed the source.could you please check it.